# Member variable does not accept array with elements

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, class

After updating WordPress to 6.0.2, I get the "white screen of death" - just stating that

> there is a critical error

with no further explanation.

After some debugging I located the line, that produces the error:
`/wp-content/plugins/jet-theme-core/includes/locations.php line 53`

It's a function of the class `Jet_Theme_Core_Locations` that assigns an array to `$this->_locations[ $id ]`

With these declarations

```
private $_locations     = array();
public $test = array();
private $_test = array();
```

I tested some statements and found out that

```
$this->_locations = true;    // works
$this->_locations = "test";  // works
$this->_locations = array(); // works
$this->_locations = array("test");           // produces a critical error
$this->_locations = array("test" => "test"); // produces a critical error
$this->_locations[] = "test";                // produces a critical error
$this->_locations["test"] = "test";          // produces a critical error
$test = array("test" => "test"); // works
$this->test = array();           // works
$this->test = array("test");     // works
$this->_test = array();          // works
$this->_test = array("test");    // works
```

I must be missing something. Probably something really obvious. But I can't figure out, what it is.

[Edit:]
The PHP log file says:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Elementor\\Post_CSS_File' not found in /wp-content/plugins/jet-theme-core/includes/locations.php:106
```

Comment: `there is a critical error, whith no further explanation`...you need to check the PHP error log file for details

Comment: Seems like working fine: https://3v4l.org/Q2IIR  . Check what @ADyson  suggested.

Comment: Turn on both WordPress and PHP error reporting. As posted, although changing that assignment might remove the error, the actual error should be coming from somewhere else since that property isn’t typed and there doesn’t appear to be a syntax error

Comment: Provide the error message from the log file.

Comment: Me: "I must be missing something. Probably something really obvious." Answer: "look into the log file" - Yep, that was, what I was missing. I have a log file. Doh.

Comment: I cannot imagine how the line `$this->_locations = array("test")` could produce the error you've shared

Comment: @NicoHaase That's what baffled me, too. Turns out, it wasn't this part of the code that produced the actual error, but the faulty code was only executed, when $this->_locations had elements to loop over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `enqueue_styles()` loops over `$this->_locations` and calls `Elementor\Post_CSS_File` but doesn't find it. If `$this->_locations` is empty or not an array at all, it doesn't touch `Elementor\Post_CSS_File` and the error doesn't occur.

As suggested [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/fatal-error-uncaught-error-class-elementorpost_css_file-not-found-in/), I replaced

```
$css_file = new Elementor\Post_CSS_File( $template_id );
```

with

```
$css_file = new Elementor\Core\Files\CSS\Post( $template_id );
```

Now everything works fine.